# Obtener el nombre de las bases de datos almacenadas en un SGBD

Tags: java, mysql, base-de-datos, postgresql, ms-access

estoy tratando de hacer una conexión a un gestor de base de datos (postgresql, Mysql y Access) y quisiera saber si hay alguna manera de conectarme al gestor y sacar la información del nombre de las bases de datos que están almacenadas allí. Todo esto utilizando JAVA.
Necesito obtener el nombre de las bases de datos almacenadas en los 3 gestores no al mismo tiempo sino utilizando funciones, métodos o clases distintos. Estoy siguiendo el procedimiento estándar de conexión a una base de datos, pero no quiero conectarme a una especifica sino quiero obtener el nombre de todas.

```
String stringConnection = "jdbc:postgresql://" + this.host + ":" + this.port + "/" + this.database; 

Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver").newInstance(); 

conn = DriverManager.getConnection(stringConnection, this.user, this.password);

 //Son las principales líneas de conexión que estoy empleando.
```

Comment: de esos 3 gestores a la vez? que haz tratado? sería importante que las [ask] y de paso hagas el [tour] pues debes mostrar un avance

Comment: dudo que con un solo procedimiento puedas acceder a las 3, pues son tecnologías dieferentes, drivers diferentes, si revisas por ejemplo el driver de conexión para mysql en java solo esta diseñado para ese mismo; te convendría acotar o refactorizar tu problema

Comment: No al mismo tiempo, sino en procedimientos distintos.

Comment: te aconsejo para evitar el cierre de tu pregunta que de hecho es muy interesante coloques toda esta información en tu pregunta asi como el código que llevas al momento

Comment: El driver que se utiliza para interactuar con las bases de datos en Java se llama `JDBC`. Y existe uno particular por cada manejador de base de datos. Que yo sepa no existe una versión de `JDBC` que sea multiple (que permita interactuar con MySQL, Postgresql, Oracle, SQL Server, etc. Para hacer lo que quieres tendrías que incorporar cada versión de `JDBC`, y crear algo como una `clase` que se vaya conectado uno por uno, recogiendo la información y guardándola en un array o algo parecido y luego sacar toda la información de ese array.

Comment: Si, esos procedimientos estarán separados por clases. Lo que quiero saber es si habrá un comando, función  o procedimiento de cada driver que me permita lograrlo.

Comment: `JDBC` tiene como función intercomunicar nuestra aplicación con el manejador de base de datos. La obtención de las bases de datos que existen en un manejador cualquiera se logra mediante una consulta como cualquier otra. Por lo general esta consulta suele ser `SHOW DATABASES` . Se trataría entonces de enviar esa consulta y recuperar los resultados... tal y como si se tratase de un `SELECT`. Sólo que quizá necesites ciertos privilegios para poder mostrar las bases de datos y debas verificar en cada gestor de bases de datos cómo devuelve la información para poder manejarla adecuadamente.

Answer (score 0):

Tendrías que tener 3 métodos, uno para cada conexión. En cada método de por si ya pones la url del `JDBC y en esa url está el nombre de la base de datos, ya si luego quieres el nombre lo que deberías hacer es lo siguiente.

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pedidos?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"
//Como vez ahí esta mi bd pedidos
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "usuario", "pass");
String name = conn.getMetaData().getUrl();
//Obtienes lo mismo que la url, debes de ver como parsear esa url para obtener el nombre.
```